# jquery selectors work in all browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

Do the jquery selectors 'first', 'odd', work in all browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it works properly in all browsers. The main advantage of using javascript framework is that they handle all the browser compatibility issues.

Check the below link for more details -

http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 6):

Yes. The entire point of jQuery is to support cross-browser comparability (per the [home page](http://jquery.com/), it supports IE 6.0+, FF 2.0+, Safari 3.0+, Opera 9.0+ and Chrome). If you do come across a bug, [please report it to the jQuery team](http://bugs.jquery.com/report).